# Are lambdas garbage collected?

Tags: java, lambda, garbage-collection

If I'm not mistaken, under certain situations a lambda in Java is generated as an anonymous class instance. For example, in this code the lambda needs to capture a variable from the outside:

```
final int local = 123456;
list.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + local));
```

Does it means that the garbage collector will claim the lambda as an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it won't; this is not how lambdas work.

Yes, a class instance is generated; no, it won't fade out.

A lambda is a call site which is linked using `invokedynamic`; after the initial linkage is done, the JIT is free to kick in and may, for instance, inline the code. So, your "class instance" is only really a class at the beginning.

If the lambda is a method reference for instance, ultimately the JIT will inline the lambda into an invoke{static,virtual,interface,special} according to what this method reference is. The work done by the JIT is however vendor-dependent.

Comment: Where does that -1 come from?

Comment: Yeah, i'd like to know. Your answer feels very solid, so i'll mark it as valid. Thank you.

Comment: Because JIT does not really affect garbage collection as you describe it. The reason, the instance is not collected is a result of how the lambda expression is bootstrapped. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter where did I ever mention the GC at all??

Comment: The question is merely about GC.

Comment: @fge: I think there are a number of unclear or incorrect statements in this post. What do you mean with "fade out"? What does this mean?: "So, your "class instance" is only really a class at the beginning." How can a "class instance" be a "class"? What do you mean by "A lambda is a call site"?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, instances that represent lambda expressions are garbage collected just like any other object. Even the classes that implement the functional interface can be collected, if the class that contains the lambda expression gets eligible for collection.

The reason that the above lambda is not collected is the result of an optimization by the lambda bootstrap method. Normally, a bootstrap method binds a static factory method to the invokedynamic call site. That factory takes all required variables of the enclosing methods and a reference to the declaring instance, if required. The factory then creates an instance of the class that represents the lambda and stores all values in fields of this instance.

However, if a lambda expression does not have any state, the bootstrap method creates a singleton which is then directly bound to the lambda expression's call site. Naturally, this singleton cannot be collected before the enclosing class is.

If you want to read more about how invokedynamic and lambda expressions work, I recently wrote a summary: http://mydailyjava.blogspot.no/2015/03/dismantling-invokedynamic.html?m=1

This is the current implementation of HotSpot, the bootstrapper can change in the future.